# I want to retrieve campaign,source and medium of my website on signup button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0, google-analytics

I want to know from which source and medium the current request is coming, when the user clicks on the signup button. On the server side, I am using .NET MVC.

I don't know how to use _utmZ cookie and retrieve data from it.

I tried using analytics.js but I cant find campaign, source and medium.

Answer (score 0):

Universal Analytics (analytics.js) does not store source/medium information in cookies (the utmz cookie belongs to the now outdated version of analytics, you should not rely on that).

So you can't take the info from Analytics (at least not in realtime), you'd have to determine source/medium on the landing page yourself and store it a cookie of your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch information from query parameter strings `utm_source utm_medium` etc.

Additionally for Google analytics campaign information is always available in GA interface. You can check by Acquisition -> campaign on left menu in GA interface regardless of version you're using.

Assuming if you want to just store the information you can fire event call on signup button and retrieve data using GA api and map campaign information with your signup events.

Comment: How do i get the Acquisition -> campaign date using API?